# jQuery changing the style of an element

Tags: jquery, hover

Is it possible to change the style of span.arrow to `border-color: transparent transparent #FFF transparent;` to `border-color: transparent transparent #FAFCFF transparent;` when you hover over the first list item in the UL with an ID of #links? I have no clue how I'd do this, I've already tried several non-working codes. Site I'm trying this on: [jamestestblog](http://jamestestblog.tumblr.com/)

Comment: Thanks to whoever thumbed this down for no reason! I need help and I'm not good with jQuery, lay off god.

Comment: I suspect the -1 was for the fact you haven't provided any code. What code have you tried? What does your HTML look like?

Comment: @AlastairPitts Well I deleted it because it wasn't working... but it was using the .hover(); and .css() jquery plugins.

Comment: By using the .hover() as you mention, and by having some CSS predefined - you should use the jquery attributes function - $("#links").addClass("hover"); and $("#links").removeClass("hover");

Comment: Repost back your attempt and I can try to help you from there :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got your requirement, please try the following and see whether it's working

Add a CSS rule

```
span.arrow.hover { border-color: transparent transparent #FAFCFF transparent }
```

then js:

```
$('#links li:first').hover(
   function() { $('span.arrow').addClass('hover'); },
   function() { $('span.arrow').removeClass('hover'); }
);
```